# File Upload from WebApp to Joomla API

Tags: joomla-4.x, javascript, joomla-api, restful-api, joomla-5.x

I have successfully programmed a Joomla 4/5 API to generate an API web service. There is a kind of weird bug uploading files though, because it basically works on localhost - but on the live system I get the following error:

```
2023-11-07T20:10:12+00:00   CRITICAL 77.8.3.4   error   Uncaught Throwable of type Joomla\CMS\Router\Exception\RouteNotFoundException thrown with message "Page not found". Stack trace: #0 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(754): Joomla\CMS\Router\Router->parse()
#1 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(244): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->route()
#2 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(306): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()
#3 [ROOT]/includes/app.php(58): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#4 [ROOT]/index.php(32): require_once('...')
#5 {main}
```

It seems that Joomla cannot find the API endpoint, when called from JavaScript Node.js (Netlify). It does not reach the API controller.  Joomla 4 does not log any error message. Joomla 5 at least prints the above message. -

The registerRoutes() of the Plugin looks like this:

```
 $routes = [
...
   new Route(
     ['POST'],       
     'v1/....fileupload/:id',
     'myclass.fileupload',
     ['id' => '(\d+)']
   )
...]
```

The defined Route can be successfully called on localhost or by using Postman (with "multipart/form-data") via this URL:  `https://myjoomlaapiserver.com/api/v1/...fileupload/1`

On the JavaScript Side (Vue 3/ Nuxt 3) the code calling the endpoint generates a file Blob and sends it to the Joomla API.

```
const results = await $fetch(
  url,
  {
     method: "POST",
     body: newFormData,
     headers: {
       // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
       'Accept': '*/*', //! Ohne gibt's einen 406 Error
        Authorization: `Bearer ${config.BEARER}`,
     },
  }
);
```

More details on the Vue client here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77232507/file-upload-through-pinia-store-and-the-nuxt-3-server-api

Any ideas why this works on localhost but not on Joomla 4 or Joomla 5?
How to get better debugging info on the Joomla side?

Comment: What is the full endpoint URL? Is your live site installed in a subdirectory?

Comment: The Joomla API endpoint URL is on another Server. It works with Postman ("multipart/form-data").

Comment: Added some code to the question above

Comment: Can you try changing URL so it includes `index.php`, e.g. `https://myjoomlaapiserver.com/api/index.php/v1/...`?

Comment: I tried it, but it did not help.

Comment: Is your site running on Nginx server? Is your site updated from J3?

Comment: The problem occurs on both a web hosting package and a web hosting company's virtual server. Both appear to be running nginx in front of their Apache server. - The Joomla 5 was long time ago migrated from J3 to J4.

Comment: I'm almost certain server configuration needs to be updated to allow `api/index.php` handle SEF URLs. See Joomla documentation for Nginx https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx. For Apache, inspect the `htaccess.txt` that ships with Joomla (note it has an error which prevents API from working when J! is installed in a subdirectory).

Comment: Thanks @Sharky, I will check with the web hosting company and let you know.

Comment: @Sharky, no feedback from the web hosting company yet. How can I investigate this bug myself? I am wondering why it works on localhost and only makes trouble when sending file blob on POST requests.

Comment: FYI: I have the same problem with a fresh J5 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I have finally found the cause of the error.

On the Joomla side, you need to set the CORS parameter Access-Control-Allow-Headers to `Content-Type,X-Joomla-Token,Authorization,Accept` in the Joomla main configuration!

The main cause of the problem is on the server side of the Nuxt 3 application: Netlify blocks file processing and redirection to Joomla, because it mainly a service to server static content. - The solution is to communicate the file upload from the Nuxt 3 / Vue 3 web app client/browser directly.

```
const url = `${config.public.fileServerUrl}/api/v1/fileuploadroute`;
const results = await useFetch(
    url,
    {
       method: "POST",
       body: form_data,
       headers: {
          // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',  // DISABLE
          'Accept': '*/*', //! Ohne gibt's einen 406 Error
          Authorization: `Bearer ${config.public.fileBearerToken}`,
       },
    }
);
```

As the Joomla API token is exposed to the web application client, I generated an additional one just for file uploads. - Options to hide the API token from the client could be writing a Netlify function or using Vercel. I haven't tried both yet.